# Почему функция не считает сумму строки таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть [страничка на гитхабе](https://konstantinshirmanov.github.io/LW6/tablePage.html). После нажатия на кнопку в последних ячейках строк таблицы должна посчитаться сумма всех ячеек строки, но моя функция выводит `NaN. Почему?

Сам скрипт функции:

```
 function cols (){
var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j =0; j<columns.length; j++){ 

        if (!isNaN(columns[j].innerHTML)) sum = columns[j];
        columns[columns.length-1].innerHTML= +sum;
    }

    if (sum %2 == 0) rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    else rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    }

}
```

html-код:

```
      <table width="200" border="1" id='tbl'>
      <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>         
      <td>3</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>         
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>14</td>
      </tr>

     </table>

     <input type="button" name ="sumInTableButton" onclick ="cols()" value="Посчитать сумму в строке">
```

Comment: innerHTML дает строку. Переведите ее в число. И прибавлять надо не ячейку а её содержимое в виде числа. sum += parseInt(columns[j].innerHTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил функцию таким образом:

```
function cols (){
var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j =0; j<columns.length-1; j++){ 

        if (!isNaN(parseInt(columns[j].innerHTML))) sum+= parseInt( columns[j].innerHTML);
        columns[columns.length-1].innerHTML = sum;
    }

    if (sum %2 == 0) rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    else rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить код следующим образом

```
function cols (){
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        var sum = 0;
        for (var j =0; j<columns.length; j++){   
            if (!isNaN(columns[j].innerHTML)) {
                sum += columns[j].innerHTML * 1;   
            }
        }
        columns[columns.length-1].innerHTML = sum;

       if (sum %2 == 0) rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
       else rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    }
}
```